# Oracle DB Express 11 - How to show SGA PGA info?

Tags: database, oracle

How to show information about SGA/PGA usage?

Using sql command line or sql developer (?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SGA is just `show sga` in sqlplus (the command line tool) and for the PGA you should find a query here:

[http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4269591917792](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:4269591917792)

This is the query:

```
 SELECT name, sum(value/1024) "Value - KB"
   FROM v$statname n,
        v$session s,
        v$sesstat t
  WHERE s.sid=t.sid
    AND n.statistic# = t.statistic#
    AND s.type = 'USER'
    AND s.username is not NULL
    AND n.name in ('session pga memory', 'session pga memory max', 
        'session uga memory', 'session uga memory max')
  GROUP BY name
 /
```